# Vagrant Ubuntu Can't Resize Disk

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a vagrant instance (using VirtualBox), and I'm using the [vagrant-disksize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXvsG.png) plugin to allocate more disk space for it.

However the Ubuntu instance doesn't seem to "see" the extra space.

VirtualBox settings show 20GB virtual and ~6GB actual.

Further inspection of the Ubuntu settings show that only ~6GB are available.

How can I fix this?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the doc of the plugin states

> Depending on the guest, you may need to resize the partition and the
>   filesystem from within the guest. At present the plugin only resizes
>   the underlying disk.

You can follow the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31747505/4296747) for the remaining steps after the virtual disk has been increased

Answer (score 0):

You now need to resize the partition and filesystem as pointed in the documentation. (also mentioned by Frédéric in his answer).

I found it was much easier to use Gparted Live Editor to do the resizing and followed the below steps

https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/faq/administration/extend-disk/